# Bring close 3D point to another 3D point equivalence

Tags: linear-algebra

Having 2 point in 3D field   - $\text{p1(x1,y1,z1) , p2(x2,y2,z2)}$ .

How could I generate the equivalence , $f$ which take parameter $t\in[0,1]$ and bring $p1$ closer to $p2$ as well as $t$ increase such that $f(1)=p2$ and $f(0)=p1$  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a convex combination: $f=(1-t) p_1 + t p_2$, $t\in [0,1]$.